# get json data in rateit aria-valuenow tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, handlebars.js

I am getting json data inside handlebar template. I need to fetch the rating number in rateit plugin `aria-valuenow=""`

If I give the json name in span, its fetching the data but when I add the same syntax inside the a`ria-valuenow=""` it is not working.

Working code

```
<span>{{this.rating}}</span>
```

The above code gives result like `<span>3</span>`

I need the same value to be inside the  aria-valuenow="" like  `aria-valuenow="3"`

I tried giveng like this  `aria-valuenow="{{this.rating}}"` but this didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Unfortunately you can't do this in handlebars.</strike>

**Update:**

```
aria-valuenow="{{this.rating}}"
```

This is working, not sure why it didn't worked for you.

However you can add it using jQuery like below

```
$('span').prop('aria-valuenow', this.rating);
```

May be after loading the template

Comment: Should I leave the aria-valuenow="" blank or add 0?

Comment: @Sowmya You can leave blank in you template `aria-valuenow=""`

Comment: I did this but it is giving output blank only. like aria-valuenow=""

Comment: @Sowmya I tired it as you mentioned it is working.  check this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/dASav/2/  Inspect the element, and you can find it

Comment: @Sowmya After a few trail and errors, it seems the attribute is only seen when inspecting but not getting selected.  So follow my procedure, check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/dASav/3/